# Change frequency time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, frequency

As input I have a time series known at daily time points. We may refer to this time series as `_x_`. The object `_x_` is a time series, i.e. consisting of dates and measurements.

I would like to investigate the effect of keeping the time series constant in each month. In other words, I would like to have a new time series `_y_` that still has a daily frequency but the observations in the months are kept constant equal to the first value in the month.

I have looked into this and tried to use the `'tempdisagg'` package, specifically the `'td'` function. However, this seems too complicated for my purpose and requires a formula as input. Furthermore supposing each month has 30 days will create a discrepancy between `_x_` and `_y_`, which is not desirable as the length of the time series is several years.

*Is there a solution to enable this?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creation of x (time series)

```
x <- ts(seq(1:62),  frequency = 365, start = c(2017, as.numeric(format(as.Date("2017-12-01"), "%j"))) )
```

Creation of a dataframe (db) with the timeseries, the daily and monthly data

```
library(lubridate)
tms <- date_decimal(as.numeric(time(x)))
y_m<-as.character(substr(as.character(tms),1,7))
db<-as.data.frame(cbind(as.numeric(x),as.character(tms),y_m))
colnames(db)<-c("time_series","y_m_d","y_m")
```

Extraction of the first value for each month

```
db_first<-db[!duplicated(db$y_m),]
```

Creation of the final output

```
db_merge<-as.data.frame(merge(x=db,y=db_first,by="y_m",all=T))
db_final<-as.data.frame(cbind(as.character(db_merge$y_m),as.numeric(as.character(db_merge$time_series.y))))
colnames(db_final)<-c("y_m","time_series")
       y_m time_series
1  2017-12           1
2  2017-12           1
3  2017-12           1
4  2017-12           1
5  2017-12           1
6  2017-12           1
7  2017-12           1
8  2017-12           1
9  2017-12           1
10 2017-12           1
11 2017-12           1
12 2017-12           1
13 2017-12           1
14 2017-12           1
15 2017-12           1
16 2017-12           1
17 2017-12           1
18 2017-12           1
19 2017-12           1
20 2017-12           1
21 2017-12           1
22 2017-12           1
23 2017-12           1
24 2017-12           1
25 2017-12           1
26 2017-12           1
27 2017-12           1
28 2017-12           1
29 2017-12           1
30 2017-12           1
31 2017-12           1
32 2018-01          32
33 2018-01          32
34 2018-01          32
35 2018-01          32
36 2018-01          32
37 2018-01          32
38 2018-01          32
39 2018-01          32
40 2018-01          32
41 2018-01          32
42 2018-01          32
43 2018-01          32
44 2018-01          32
45 2018-01          32
46 2018-01          32
47 2018-01          32
48 2018-01          32
49 2018-01          32
50 2018-01          32
51 2018-01          32
52 2018-01          32
53 2018-01          32
54 2018-01          32
55 2018-01          32
56 2018-01          32
57 2018-01          32
58 2018-01          32
59 2018-01          32
60 2018-01          32
61 2018-01          32
62 2018-01          32
```